# Show available stock quantity on product page

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly I would like to apologise if this question has been answered somewhere else but I am unable to find what I am looking for as I am new to PHP and assume I need this to solve my problem.

I have built a website and am using Mals-e shopping cart. I have everything up and running but I would like to show how many products are still in stock under the product description and if there are no items in stock. For example:

Available stock: 2

or

Sold Out

I have read that I need a text file with product name, price and quantity, a PHP file to read and rewrite the quantity available and out put the results on the product page and a mypage.php page but I really don't know where to start. I've spent days trying to sort this out.

I have Mysql database with some items in table called (items) with available quantity but don't know how to go about sorting it out. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: why dont you used opencart, magento or oscommerce? this has the capability to know your stocks and the once who are sold out?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code you're using to display the product, it's hard to say buy all you should need is something like:

```php
<?php
// get the product and stock level
if($product->numberInStock > 0) {
    echo 'Available: ' . $product->numberInStock;
} else {
    echo 'Out of stock';
}
```

If you're editing a phtml type template (HTML with embedded PHP), you might display it like:

```php
<? if($product->numberInStock > 0): ?>
    <p>Available: <?= $product->numberInStock; ?></p>
<? else ?>
    <p>Out of stock</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry OddEssay. I have the product description followed by:

<div id="product-select">
<form action="http://ww8.aitsafe.com/cf/add.cfm" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="000000"> 
<input type="hidden" name="nocart"> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.co.uk/shop/category/baby_girls/babygirls_cupcake.htm"> 
<b>Qty:</b> <input type="text" name="qty" size="1">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="Baby Girls Sock Cupcake"> 
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="4.85">
<input name="submit" value="Add to Cart" type="submit">
</form>
</div>

Comment: That looks like the html output (What you see in the browser) not the PHP code on the server - You'll need to find where the product display is been generated on the backend and tinker with that, or, as has been mentioned in other comments look at something opencart or oscommerce that'll take care of a lot of this stuff out of the box.

Comment: I have a site hosted on pappashop that uses Cpanel and I am able to use the stock inventory and such for that. The site I am asking about is hosted on the same account but it does not allow me use the same functions. It is just a basic htm site with no php scripts or anything as I don't know how to use it. I just wondered if there was a way to add total available stock without having to host somewhere else to get these functions. I tried Magento but could not manipulate to get the same layout as I have so gave up. Lazy I know! I'll look at Opencart. Your help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Wow, err, you might want to start somewhere even simpler then like http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php if you want to go down that route - Or go with something hosted which avoids you needed to mess with the code at all.

Comment: Ok I'll have a look :)

Comment: OddEssay, I had a look at the site you suggested and just want say that was a great help. I got stock level to show up on my page. Cheers! Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, found out following.

Inside your catalog/product type template you can use this:

```
<?php 
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_qty = $_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
?>
<p>
  <?php if($_qty > 0): ?>
    Available: <?php echo $_qty; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    Out of stock
  <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start($_POST['quantity']);
if(isset($_POST['quantity']))
{
$postedquantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$productQuantity="20";
if($postedquantity<$productQuantity){
    echo "In stock";
    echo "<br/>";


}
$productQuantity=$productQuantity-$postedquantity;
    echo $productQuantity."Remaining";
}
```

You can even do like this,storing quantity value in session and everytime it's posted it will check whether it is in stock or not and it will show how much quantity is remaining.